# Uploading CSV into GAE datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, csv, google-cloud-datastore, export-to-csv

I am using GAE's high replication datastore. I previously downloaded a table in csv using this:

```
appcfg.py download_data --application=<your_app_id> --kind=<kind> --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/[remote_api_path] --filename=<data-filename>
```

Now I made some modifications into that CSV file, and I want to upload it to replace the online data. So I used this:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=bulkloader.yaml --filename=<data-filename> --kind=<kind> --url=http://your_app_id.appspot.com/[remote_api_path]
```

This successfully uploaded the data, but the problem is that now all of the newly uploaded keys (including references) look like this: `name=99764` instead of `id=99764`

GAE didn't recognize that both are the same thing, so it didn't replace the ones out there, it added new ones. But now the references are now broken.

In the `bulkloader.yaml`, I have this:

```
- kind: Kind
  connector: csv
  connector_options:
    # TODO: Add connector options here--these are specific to each connector.
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

Is this part: `transform.key_id_or_name_as_string` causing the problem? if so then how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure but maybe this can help you. I have used this only for *link* a ReferenceProperty, not for replace data

```
- property: __key__
      external_name: key
      import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('key', key_is_id=True)
      export_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string
```

edit:

```
- property: category
  external_name: category
  import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('Category', key_is_id=True)
```

'Category' in uppercase is the Model referenced from the property 'category'. In csv file I have a string like '123456' and in datastore the ID of Category Kind is '123456'. In this way GAE has associated the referenceproperty to the relative Kind otherwise it would be a simple string. Now in your case is different because you work with the Key for replace the data and I don't have experience in this sense.

Comment: should it be `import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('key', key_is_id=True)` or should I change 'key' to the name of the Kind? because among the automatically generated was this: import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('Topic'). So it seems that I should put the name of the Kind in place of 'key'
but the weird thing is that both worked, I am concerned that there could be something I am missing that may cause problems later on

Comment: `- property: category  /  import_transform: transform.create_foreign_key('Category', key_is_id=True)`

'Category' in uppercase is the Model referenced from the property 'category'. In csv file I have a string like '123456' and in datastore the ID of Category Kind is `123456`.

In this way GAE has associated the referenceproperty to the relative Kind otherwise it would be a simple string.

Now in your case is different because you work with the Key for replace the data and I don't have experience in this sense.

Comment: Yes, 'Category' should be replaced by the Kind's name. It works perfectly! thanks!!